# Java EE SSO Best Practices

Tags: java, ssl, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

I found a great white paper (by Sun) about integrating Kerberos, JAAS and the GSS-API together for a heavy-duty SSO system. Unfortunately the article was written for Java 1.4 and is several years old.

**(1) I'm wondering: is this "triumverate" (Kerberos-JAAS-GSS, or *KJG* for short) still (as of J6 and coming soon, J7) the predominant SSO mechanism for Java EE apps? If not, what is, and can you explain its architecture briefly?**

My application would also require some secure web services.  Prior to reading this paper, I was considering using SSL to secure the transport and either XWSS or (more likely) Apache's WSS4J framework for authentication/sigs/encryption:

**(2) Is *KJG* (or whatever solution you recommended for Question 1 above) capable of providing secure web services? For instance, would it be possible to use KJG instead of WSS4J/SSL?**

This second question is my attempt to see if I can reuse a lot of the SSO code for a secure web service implementation.  Thanks in advance for any input or nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered SAML 2.0?

Its specification contains a Web SSO profile and it is supported in popular J2EE identity products such as OpenAM (formerly known as OpenSSO). I've worked with [OpenASelect](http://www.openaselect.org) (which uses [OpenSAML](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/OpenSAML/Home)) to implement Web SSO.